# Removing part of a string before a pattern

Tags: sed

Am trying to use the sed command to remove all the text before the first numeric character in all the lines, by using the following

```
sed 's/.*[0-9]//' temp1.txt
```

However, it is removing all the text up to the last numeric character.

Comment: you should add sample input/output to clarify whether or not you want to remove the first digit as well... you text says `before` but the code you tried removes the digit

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers

Answer (score 2):

this is due to eager algorithm of sed.

use:

```
sed 's/^[^0-9]*//' temp1.txt
```

where

- `^` begining of line
- `[^0-9]` any char but 0-9
- `*` multiple time

Comment: This will also remove the first numeric character, if this is not desired, leave off the second `[0-9]`